# custom filter in mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I'm using mat-table. It has a filter which works fine with doc example:

From https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview, the original code is:

```html
    <div class="example-header">
       <mat-form-field>
         <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
       </mat-form-field>
   </div>

   <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      <!-- the rest of the code -->
   </mat-table>
```

```js
    export class TableFilteringExample {
     displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
     dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

     applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
       filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
       filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
       this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
     }
    }
    const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
     {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
     {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
     {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
     {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
     {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'}
    ];
```

With this implementation, when filter, it filter for any column.

Now I'm trying to change the filter because I want is filter just for "name" column, so I'm trying to rewrite the filter and assign to filterData.

```js
      applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
        filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
        filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
       this.dataSource.filteredData = this.filterByEmail(filterValue); 
        console.log(this.dataSource.filteredData); //value is what I want.
    }

    filterByName(filter: string): any {
      const dataFiltered = this.data.filter(function(item){
         return item.name.indexOf(filter) > -1
       })
        return dataFiltered;
    }
```

In console, I can see this.dataSource.filteredData has the data I want to print, but table is not reload.

What are I'm missing?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276404/filtering-specific-column-in-angular-material-table-in-angular-5/48400406?noredirect=1#comment84008277_48400406).

It's necessary to rewrite `filterPredicate`, and just use it as usual, `filterPredicate` needs to return `true` when filter passes and `false` when it doesn't

```js
export interface Element {
 name: string;
 position: number;
 weight: number;
 symbol: string;
}


dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
/* configure filter */
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = 
  (data: Element, filter: string) => data.name.indexOf(filter) != -1;


applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
   filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
   filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
   this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
 }
```

Comment: adding 
this.dataSource.filterPredicate =  (data: Element, filter: string) => data.name.indexOf(filter) != -1;

 in ngOnInit() method and the IDE shows this:

TS2322: Type '(data: Element, filter: string) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(data: string, filter: string) => boolean'.   Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Element'.

anyone know why?

Answer (score 15):

Don't forget to apply `.trim().toLowerCase()` on your data or you may encounter unexpected results. See my example below:

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data:
  {name: string}, filterValue: string) =>
  data.name.trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) !== -1;

applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that all fields of the class displayed in table rows, are subject to filtering, even if you do not display that field as a column.

```
export class City {
  id: number;//is not displayed in mat table
  code: string;
  name: string;
  country:Country;
}
```

Any filter for the dataSource of city table, also applies to id column, which generally we do not display to the end user.

```
//this filter will also apply to id column
this.cityDataSource.filter = filterValue;
```

Comment: how to avoid id from the filter?

Comment: filterPredicate of data source may be used as mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

when using parent-child componenet (or service with say `observable`) you must always in the component containing the `MatTableDataSource` set an `"applyFilter"` function (name not matters)

in the table component i added `@Input`'s for the filter string value as a `FormControl`, and sent a filter function (`filterfn`)

```
  @Input() data: any[];
  @Input() filterControl: FormControl;
  @Input() filterfn: (data: any, filter: string) => boolean;
```

in the init

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.filterfn
    this.dataSource.data = this.data;
    this.initExpandedDefaultValues();
    //my "applyFilter"
    this.filterControl.valueChanges.subscribe(searchValue => this.dataSource.filter = searchValue)
  }
```

in parent html

```
<div *ngIf="users">
    <expended-table [data]="users"
        [filterfn]="filterFunction"
        [filterControl]="search">
    </expended-table>
</div>
```

in parent component

```
public users:User[]
  search:FormControl = new FormControl()
  public usersFiltered:User[]

  filterFunction(u: User, searchValue: string) : boolean{
    if (searchValue) {
      let v = searchValue.trim().toLowerCase()
      if (
        u.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(v) || 
        u.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(v) || 
        //bla bla bla more tests
        u.permission.toLowerCase().includes(v)  
      )
      { return true } 
      else { return false}
    } //end if searchValue
    else 
    {
      return true
    }
  }
```