# Material DataTable filtering control

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using [Angular Material Data Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) and am trying to implement filtering accross all the values.
What i am noticing is that when using MatTableDataSource, filter only searches the top level of entities that are passed, if the entity has a related record attached it won't search it.

Is it possible control how deep a filter search goes and enable it to search the attached related entities?

**Edit 1 Example Code generated by schematics:**

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  @Input() dataSource: MatTableDataSource<TestEntity>;

  /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name', 'view_related_child'];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
```

**Edit 2 Entities:**

```
export class TestEntity {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    childEntity: ChildEntity;
}

export class ChildEntity {
    childId: string;
    childName: string;
    childDate: string;
}
```

Comment: did you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506606/custom-filter-in-mat-table)?

Comment: @fatemefazli am now, didn't pop up on my initial search

Comment: can you provide some code or stackblitz.

Comment: @fatemefazli sure but won't help much at this stage, using the schematic to generate tables so its very much rudementary.

Comment: @fatemefazli basically i want to be able to filter by entity childs data  too

Comment: any sample of TestEntity?

Comment: @fatemefazli added as per request

Answer (score 2):

you can change your apply filter method to this:

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    console.log(filterValue)

    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: TestEntity, filter: string) =>   data.childEntity.childName.indexOf(filter) != -1 
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); 
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue 
  }
```

to filter the data based on childName of childEntity,
[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datatable-dp7nxe)

Comment: Thanks @fatemefazli, what about scenarios where you want to search more than one field in related entity, or go another level lower?