# How to modify the way the data table filter works in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-datatables

I am trying to use the filter in Angular Material Data Table like -

If I search for "**MATCHED**", then both "**MATCHED**" and "**UNMATCHED**" comes up in the status column of the Data table.

I know that it is because the data object is reduced and concatenated and the filter is applied(*[from the Angular Material Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#filtering)*).

I want to display only the "**MATCHED**" status, if is search for matched.
So I am looking for a filter that will do exact word filtering instead of substrings.
How to proceed ?

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506606/custom-filter-in-mat-table?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I was not able to proceed.

Comment: What issue did you have with the post you've linked to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go - [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsjnxm?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts)

Following on from the answer that you referred to we need to define **filterPredicate** :

```
export class TableFilteringExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

  constructor() {
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: PeriodicElement, filter: string) => {
      return data.name === filter;
    }
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim();
  }
}
```

Note that `toLowerCase()` has been removed from `filterValue.trim()`.

Comment: please can you go through- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144473/how-to-filter-out-the-data-between-a-start-and-end-date-using-filterpredicate-in   @camden_kid