# mat table apply filter to one column on toggle check and reset when unchecked

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using Angular 7 and Material 2, I have a [`mat-table`](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) with several columns and beneath the table I have a [`mat-slide-toggle`](https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/overview).

When the `mat-slide-toggle` becomes `checked`, I want to filter one column (status) with an exact string match filter ('Active'). Then when the `mat-slide-toggle` is `unchecked`, I want to remove the filter from the column and display as normal.

I've looked at examples like [custom filter in mat-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506606/custom-filter-in-mat-table) where they set a custom `this.dataSource.filterPredicate` which I've been able to do okay but I'm a bit stumped on:

- When the `mat-slide-toggle` is unchecked, removing the filter.
- When using the free-text filter option above the table (see code below), to use the default filter all columns.

I think for the second point I would need to reset `this.dataSource.filterPredicate` back to its default but I'm unsure of the code to do that.

---

Here are my code examples with unnecessary parts removed to keep them to the point. The status property only has two values 'Active' & 'Inactive', I want to filter only 'Active' users.

**example.component.ts**

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  users: User[] = [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'status'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  activeUserToggle(changeEvent: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    if (changeEvent.checked) {
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate =
        (user: User, filter: string) => user.status.indexOf(filter) != -1;
    } else {

    }
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
}
```

**example.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
  </mat-form-field>

  <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> <b>Name</b> </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> <b>Status</b> </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.status}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row;
                              let even = even;
                              columns: displayedColumns;" [ngClass]="{grey: even}">
      </tr>
    </table>

    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
  </div>

  <mat-slide-toggle class="activeUserSlide" (change)="activeUserToggle($event)">Show only active users</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the values back to this.users when unchecked.

```
activeUserToggle(changeEvent: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    if (changeEvent.checked) {
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate =
        (user: User, filter: string) => user.status.indexOf(filter) != -1;
    } else {
      this.dataSource.data = this.users;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is this the only way to do it? because I am getting the data from a service/ api call so I can't reassign the data source this way

Comment: You mean you are filtering the data from api also?

Comment: When I am reassigning the datasource this way, the view not updating. I am having to do datasource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users); and also have to link the sorting and pagination again with datasource.

Comment: I think to detect changes in the table that hast to be done.