# How can I filter a MatTable with accents/diacritics?

Tags: angular, angular-material, special-characters, diacritics, mat-table

I want to filter the names of a table regardless of whether the user has entered any accents or not.

For example:

If the user enters "hydrogen", the result should bring "Hydrôgen" as it is in the table.

I use Angular 8.1.3 and Angular Material 8.0.1

Here is my code:

app.component.html:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)"  (focus)="setupFilter('name')" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
...
```

my interface:

```js
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}
```

app.component.ts:

```js
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrôgen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Béryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Bóron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'ÔLxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  setupFilter(column: string) {
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (d: any, filter: string) => {
      const textToSearch = d[column] && d[column].toLowerCase() || '';
      return textToSearch.indexOf(filter) !== -1;
    };
  }

  public removeAccents(str: string): string {
    return str.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
  }
```

I expect when user input "bo" show in table 2 lines those containing "Carbon" and "Bóron".

Comment: You can use filterPredicate refer to this link for the documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/table/api Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48540498/6850994

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code that Angular material resorts to when you use filtering in a `mat-table`

```js
filterPredicate: ((data: T, filter: string) => boolean) = (data: T, filter: string): boolean => {
  // Transform the data into a lowercase string of all property values.
  const dataStr = Object.keys(data).reduce((currentTerm: string, key: string) => {
    // Use an obscure Unicode character to delimit the words in the concatenated string.
    // This avoids matches where the values of two columns combined will match the user's query
    // (e.g. `Flute` and `Stop` will match `Test`). The character is intended to be something
    // that has a very low chance of being typed in by somebody in a text field. This one in
    // particular is "White up-pointing triangle with dot" from
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters
    return currentTerm + (data as {[key: string]: any})[key] + '◬';
  }, '').toLowerCase();

  // Transform the filter by converting it to lowercase and removing whitespace.
  const transformedFilter = filter.trim().toLowerCase();

  return dataStr.indexOf(transformedFilter) != -1;
}
```

Let's go ahead and modify this `filterPredicate()` to what you need. You have already shown how to remove the accents and diacritics in your code. We'll use this in our new `filterPredicate`.

```js
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: PeriodicElement, filter: string): boolean => {
  const dataStr = Object.keys(data).reduce((currentTerm: string, key: string) => {
    return (currentTerm + (data as { [key: string]: any })[key] + '◬');
  }, '').normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLowerCase();

  const transformedFilter = filter.trim().normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLowerCase();

  return dataStr.indexOf(transformedFilter) != -1;
  }
}
```

We remove accents/diacritics from both the values in the table as well as the filter value so that even if the user happens to enter characters which have accents/diacritics, the filter will continue to filter correctly.

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-filter-predicate).