# Filter MatTableDataSource using contents of array

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a table within my Angular app that displays user data within its rows. I want to be able to filter this table using an Array of strings that represent user emails. If the user's email exists in the array, then I don't want the user to be displayed in the table.

I've had a look into filtering Angular material tables, [specifically here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506606/custom-filter-in-mat-table?rq=1) where they use a single string to filter the table. All the examples I seem to find also involve using a single string, for example from the user specifying a filter string via an input.

However, I can't find any solutions to using an array of strings to filter the data. Do I need to concatenate the whole array into a string and then pass this into the `filterPredicate` property?

```js
    applyAddedUserFilter() {
        this._usersService.addedUsers$.subscribe((addedUsers: AddedUser[]) => {
          let addedUserEmails: string[] = addedUsers.map(({ email }) => email);

          this.users.filterPredicate = (user: GoogleUser, filter: string) => { //<-- What exactly do I need to do here to use my string[] to filter my table's results?
            //Unsure what I need to do here.
          }
        });
      }
```

Also once I have the filter predicate set, where do I need to call this method. Is it enough to be able to call the method once the table has been constructed?

Comment: maybe try something like this: ```let filteredData = this.users.filter(user => !(addedUserEmails.indexOf(user.email) > -1));``` You can then add it like this --> ```this.dataSource.data = filteredData;```

Comment: yes. I would suggest to do this instead of filterpredicate and directly filter the array and set it to the datasource.data. This should work.

Comment: @sagat Can you edit the original post to show me how you're implementing this? If I try doing `this.users.filter(user => !(addedUserEmails.indexOf(user.email) > -1));` I get a compiler error.

Comment: let m,e understanfd first --> addedUserEmails is the array with the filter conditions, means, if the email is in there you dont want to show the user in the table. What is the users array called, that u want to filter. Can u post the whole component.ts

Comment: `this.users` is `users: MatTableDataSource<GoogleUser> = new MatTableDataSource([]);`, all I want to do is filter the data so that if any emails in the data source exist in the `addedUserEmails` they are not displayed in the table

Comment: okay i made a stackblitz. Answering in a sec

Comment: Mate it might be that u have to do this MatTableDataSource<GoogleUser[]>, u didnt specify a collection of users but a single User.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
applyAddedUserFilter() {
    this._usersService.addedUsers$.subscribe((addedUsers: AddedUser[]) => {
      let addedUserEmails: string[] = addedUsers.map(user => user.email);

      this.dataSource.data = this.users.filter((user: GoogleUser) => !(addedUserEmails.indexOf(user.email) > -1));
    });
  }
```

Here is a stackblitz: [Material Table Filter](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uo9z12)

Comment: `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'String' has no compatible call signatures`. That's the compiler error I get when attempting to use that line of code.

Comment: Did u check the stackblitz? Couldbu Provide your while component Code?

Comment: This is because ur GoogleUser Type and String are not the same types.