# angular 7 material table - filter is not working properly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I created a page where I am showing angular material table data. On top of table data I put a filter input to show the data in filtered format. Things are working fine but i observed a strange and unexpected angular behavior. For some of characters, it is showing filtered rows on each key strokes, but for some other characters it does not show rows on keystrokes.

**listusers.component.html**

```
 <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter" autocomplete="off">
  </mat-form-field>

  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.index}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="gender">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Gender </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.gender}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="score">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Score </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.score}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index" 
    ></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**listusers.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ListService } from '../services/list.service';
import { User } from '../model/user.model';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'listusers',
  templateUrl: './listusers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listusers.component.css']
})
export class ListusersComponent implements OnInit {
  public users: User[] = [];
  displayedColumns = [ 'position','name', 'gender', 'score'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<User>; 

  constructor(private listsrv:ListService) { }

  ngOnInit() {      
    this.loaddata();

    if(this.dataSource){
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: User, filtersJson: string) => {
        const matchFilter = [];
        const filters = JSON.parse(filtersJson);

        filters.forEach(filter => {
          const val = data[filter.id] == null ? '' : data[filter.id];
          matchFilter.push(val.toLowerCase().includes(filter.value.toLowerCase()));
        });
          return matchFilter.every(Boolean);
      };
    }
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
    console.log('filterValue',filterValue)
  }

  loaddata(){
    this.listsrv.getList()
    .subscribe(
      result => { 
        for(var key in result){ 
            this.users.push(result[key])
        } 
      },
      error => {console.log(' error',error)},
      () => {console.log(this.users)
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users);        
      }
    ) 
  }
}
```

Some CSS is also there but not sharing as it to reduce the length of ques. The data which I am using is coming from a http service call

```
getList(){return this.http.get(this.url+'/list');}
```

Which is actually calling a route function on server and returns json object.

**list.route.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var jsonobj = [ 
    {name:"john",gender:"male", score:345,},
    {name:"alice",gender:"female",score:678},
    {name:"paul",gender:"male",score:263},
    {name:"tia",gender:"female",score:620},
    {name:"michel",gender:"male",score:458},
    {name:"akbar",gender:"male",score:382},
    {name:"simon",gender:"male",score:193},
    {name:"albela",gender:"male",score:193}
  ]
    console.log('list route called')
    res.send(jsonobj) 
})
module.exports = router;
```

I tried to make project in stackblitz.com and plunker but couldn't replicate issue for some setup related problems.  I observed the when i press other keys like "t","j","u" etc. then it works but when i press "a" it does not show "alice" and "albela" rows. i have to keep entering and it shows rows when 3 characters are typed.

It is also not showing any error on console so i have no clue. Please have a look and suggest me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506606/custom-filter-in-mat-table)

this.dataSource.filterPredicate was not configured properly and also at wrong place. My modified listusers.component.ts is as below,

**listusers.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ListService } from '../services/list.service';
import { User } from '../model/user.model';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'listusers',
  templateUrl: './listusers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listusers.component.css']
})
export class ListusersComponent implements OnInit {
  public users; 
  displayedColumns = [ 'position','name', 'gender', 'score'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<User>;  

  constructor(private listsrv:ListService) { }

  ngOnInit() {      
    this.loaddata();
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {    
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  loaddata(){
    console.log('in function loaddata') 
    this.listsrv.getList() 
      .subscribe(result => 
                  this.users = result, 
                  error => console.log('Error :',error), 
                  () => { console.log(this.users); 
                          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users);
                          //added below line
                          this.dataSource.filterPredicate = 
                            (data: User, filter: string) => data.name.indexOf(filter) != -1;
                })
  }
}
```