# Material table - trigger filter programatically

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-table

Following this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48540498/325868) I know I can write my own `this.dataSource.filterPredicate`. This works fine as long as I search for a string. I want to filter additionally according to a used `state` (=`myFilterState`).

I try to use the predicate like

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = 
    (data: MyElement, filter: string) => data.myType.useState === this.myFilterState;
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I change `this.myFilterState` the filter is not reevaluated until I change the string of the `filter`. As long as the `filter` remains empty the `filterPredicate` is not triggered.

Is there a way to trigger it manually - despite the value of `filter`?

Answer (score 5):

After investigation of the problem I figured out that the `filterpredicate` is triggered by the source code only when the `filter` has a value. Otherwise it won't be triggered.

Therefore I come up with the solution to overwrite the internal `_filterData` with

```
this.dataSource._filterData = (data: PropertyCompact[]) => {
        this.dataSource.filteredData = data.filter(obj => this.dataSource.filterPredicate(obj, this.dataSource.filter));
            return this.dataSource.filteredData;
        };
```

and in case of an change one needs to trigger an update

```
this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription();
```

Answer (score 1):

### Warning and additional solution when using a paginator for LeO's solution

LeO's answer is very helpful, but be careful when overriding methods of a class. I tried their solution, and it worked for filtering, but my associated paginator with the table would ALWAYS show 0/0 items, even though it would correctly show the desired number of rows.

**Tl;dr** Add these lines before the `return` statement in LeO's answer

```
if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
    this.dataSource._updatePaginator(this.dataSource.filteredData.length);
  }
```

After spending hours trying to figure out why the paginator always displayed `0/0`, I eventually ran across someone with an unrelated problem who had explicitly put

```
 [length]="dataSource.filteredData.length"
```

in their `mat-paginator` html tag. When I inserted this attribute, the display showed the correct values.

I then looked at angular's [table-data-source.ts source code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/table/table-data-source.ts) for the `_filterData` method at it had these lines (lines 325-327):

```
if (this.paginator) {
  this._updatePaginator(this.filteredData.length);
}
```

I added these lines in the block of code from LeO's answer and got it to work properly without needing the length attribute of the html tag:

```
  if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
    this.dataSource._updatePaginator(this.dataSource.filteredData.length);
  }
```