# Filtering on specific columns of angular material2 table

Tags: angular, filtering, angular-material2, angular-cdk

In my angular app, there is a html page with a text box which will be used for filtering the below grid. As of now, the search is happening throughout all columns, i want to restrict it to only **ID** and **Name**. The below is the search textbox html :

```
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" shouldPlaceholderFloat="false">
            <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Please enter Name or ID number.">

            <!-- <input placeholder="Please enter Name or ID number." matInput #input (keyup)='searchElements(input.value)'> -->
        </mat-form-field>
```

and the below is the material table code :

```
   <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort fxFlex="60" class="">

                <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="padding-left:10px"> Name </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="padding-left:10px"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="cdate">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="padding-left:10px"> Creation Date </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="padding-left:10px"> {{element.cdate | date:'mediumDate'}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="createdby">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="padding-left:10px"> Created By </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="padding-left:10px"> {{element.createdby}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="padding-left:10px"> ID </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="padding-left:10px"> {{element.id}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="padding-left:10px"> Status </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell actQuestionFunction style="padding-left:10px" [config]="{ lob : { Id: element.id ,'true': 'func1', 'false':' func2'} }" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.sqldbinfo.status}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                <mat-row [routerLink]="['/overview', row.id]" (click)="setCurrent(row)" [queryParams]="{ name: row.name, Id: row.id }"  [ngClass]="{'hidden': (row.status == 'Submitted' && showSubmitted == false), 'submitted': row.status == 'Submitted'}" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns  " ></mat-row>
            </mat-table>
```

The **keyup** event in typescript file is written below

```
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
         this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
   }
```

This is the below ts file

```
    import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, AfterViewInit  } from 
                     '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { CamsService } from '../services/cams.service';
import { ActauthService } from '../actauth.service';
import { LocalDataService } from '../services/local-data.service';
import { ActService } from '../services/act.service';
import { ActModalService } from '../act-modal/act-modal-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-camslist',
  templateUrl: './camslist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./camslist.component.less']
})
export class CamslistComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns = ['name', 'cdate', 'createdby', 'camsid', 'status'];
  dataSource;
  StatusText: Array<string>;
  SubmittedButtonShowHide: Boolean;
  constructor(
              private camsService: CamsService,
              private auth: ActauthService,
              private localDataService: LocalDataService,
              private actService: ActService,
              private modalService: ActModalService) {

  }
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  showSubmitted: Boolean = false;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.getMyLogon().subscribe(
      res => {
        res.EmployeeId = 29007154;
        this.camsService.all(res).subscribe(
          cams => {
            if (cams.length === 0) {
              this.modalService.openNoCamsIdMsgModal();
            } else {
                  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(cams);
                  setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.sort = this.sort);
           }
          });
      });
  }

  // ngAfterViewInit() {
  //   setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.sort = this.sort);

  // }
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    // this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;

    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data, filter: string): 
 boolean {
      return data.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter) || 
     data.camsid.toLowerCase().includes(filter);

    };
  }
  toggleSubmitted() {
    this.showSubmitted = !this.showSubmitted;
  }

    export interface Element {
     name: string;
    cdate: string;
     createdby: string;
       id: number;
     status: string;
```

}`

Comment: This should help you get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276404/filtering-specific-column-in-angular-material-table-in-angular-5/48400406?noredirect=1#comment84008277_48400406

Comment: I could not take any help from the above link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add filterpredicate where you are updating the datasource not in `applyFilter` function.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.getMyLogon().subscribe(
      res => {
        res.EmployeeId = 29007154;
        this.camsService.all(res).subscribe(
          cams => {
            if (cams.length === 0) {
              this.modalService.openNoCamsIdMsgModal();
            } else {
                  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(cams);
                  setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.sort = this.sort);
                  //======= HERE =====//
                  this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data, filter: string): boolean {
                     return data.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter) ||  data.camsid.toLowerCase().includes(filter);
                  };
           }
          });
    });
}
```

Comment: glad to hear that :)

Comment: Can you please tell me how/where you have defined "filterPredicate"?

Comment: @Shardul just below `//======= HERE =====//` in answer

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal Yes. I got that. Is there any way we can remove a single column from datasource and apply filter on remaining columns?

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal I have a column called "id" in all my different datasources. I just don't want to consider that column for filter. Is there anything like "Exclude" or "remove"?