# How to create custom filtering using MatTableDataSource in angular 5?

Tags: angular, mat-table, angular-material-table, angular-material-5

In Angular material official website [Angular Material Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) it is mentioned that filterPredicate: ((data: T, filter: string) => boolean) will filter data based on a specific field. But don't know how to start. Is there any example is present for this.

Answer (score 15):

This answer seems to show how to use the filter predicate:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50174938/6130716

It works like so:

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: MyObject, filter: string) => {
  return data.property == filter;
};

this.dataSource.filter = myValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, @peter for the response it's working correctly.

Comment: would you do this in ngOnInit?