# Filtering specific column in Angular Material Table with filtering in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using  [mat-table](https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts). It has a filter which works fine.

Filter happened against this below data (All columns)

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {position: 14598, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 24220, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 39635, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 42027, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 53216, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 60987, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 70976, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 81297, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 90975, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 18879, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
  {position: 11209, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na'}

];
```

But Now I am trying to change the filter because I want is filter just for `"position", "name", "symbol"` column. I have gone through this example but [Filtering specific column in Angular Material table in angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276404/filtering-specific-column-in-angular-material-table-in-angular-5).

I did not understand please help me on this

[StackBlitz Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z17v3j-o8y43u?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You have to override the `filterPredicate` of your dataSource.

Here's an example of how to do it: [Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5hcooj)

---

Essentially, you want to specify what properties in your data the filter is applied to:

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data, filter: string): boolean {
    return data.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter) || data.symbol.toLowerCase().includes(filter) || data.position.toString().includes(filter);
};
```

Comment: Just to clarify, if the position of an element is `11209`, and the user types in `112`, do you want to show that element?

Comment: position is not filtering .https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5hcooj-rps6vn?file=app/table-filtering-example.ts

Comment: if the position of an element is 11209, and the user types in 112 yes need to show

Comment: We can have a dynamic include statement as well, because sometimes the no. of columns displayed can be around 20-30, like in my case

Answer (score 5):

In **Angular Material Tables**, we can create column based filters from data itself.

**Source [Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-material-table-custom-filter-using-select-box/)**

**Demo [Link](https://freakyjolly.com/demo/Angular/angular-material-table-custom-filters-for-multiple-specific-column/)**

[image]

For that, we need to override the **filterPredicate** method with **customFilter()** method

```
        ...
        ngOnInit() {
            this.getRemoteData();

            // Overrride default filter behaviour of Material Datatable
            this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.createFilter();
        }
        ...

        // Custom filter method fot Angular Material Datatable
        createFilter() {
            let filterFunction = function (data: any, filter: string): boolean {
            let searchTerms = JSON.parse(filter);
            let isFilterSet = false;
            for (const col in searchTerms) {
                if (searchTerms[col].toString() !== '') {
                isFilterSet = true;
                } else {
                delete searchTerms[col];
                }
            }

            let nameSearch = () => {
                let found = false;
                if (isFilterSet) {
                for (const col in searchTerms) {
                    searchTerms[col].trim().toLowerCase().split(' ').forEach(word => {
                    if (data[col].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) != -1 && isFilterSet) {
                        found = true
                    }
                    });
                }
                return found
                } else {
                return true;
                }
            }
            return nameSearch()
            }
            return filterFunction
        }
```

Check complete working code [here](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-material-table-custom-filter-using-select-box/)

Answer (score 3):

Adding to bugs' answer. Here's a more elaborate implementation,

```js
export class FilterTable implements AfterViewInit {
  //some datasource
  datasource //=
  displayedColumns //=insert column names on which you want to filter whether they are displayed or not, but present in the datasource

  // Apply filter to the datasource
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.datasource.filter = filterValue;
  }


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Overwriting filterPredicate here, as it needs to be done after the datasource is loaded.
    this.datasource.filterPredicate = (data, filter) => {
      var tot = false;
      for (let column of this.displayedColumns) {
        //incase if there is a date type and is displayed differently using a pipe, then convert it intorequired format before filtering
        //check if all the columnson which you are filtering are actually present
        if ((column in data) && (new Date(data[column].toString()).toString() == "Invalid Date")) {
          //if not date column
          tot = (tot || data[column].toString().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.trim().toLowerCase()) !== -1);
        } else {
          //change this to the format in which date is displayed
          var date = new Date(data[column].toString());
          var m = date.toDateString().slice(4, 7) + " " + date.getDate() + " " + date.getFullYear();
          tot = (tot || m.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.trim().toLowerCase()) !== -1);
        }
      }
      return tot;
    }
  }
}
```

Please feel free to suggest edits, if this could be improved

Comment: Your code is not compiled: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Comment: I wrote the code for reference. I've made changes, please check again

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: I'm sorry that was not a code snippet, It is just a sample code, hence you canmt run the snippet. I've changed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Material has implemented its own search feature you can override it by updating the filterPredicate property on the date source. Call the generateTable function on ngOninit() life cycle.

```
generateTable(tableData: any) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(tableData);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: any, filter: string) => {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(filter);
      let matchFound = false;
      for (let column of this.displayedColumns) {
        if(column in data) {
          if(data[column]) {
            matchFound = (matchFound || data[column].toString().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.trim().toLowerCase()) !== -1)
          }
        }
      }
      return matchFound;
    }
  }
```

Whenever you wish to apply the filter, update the filter property on dataSource to the string value to be searched.

```
applyFilter(searchValue: any) {
    this.dataSource.filter = this.filterText.trim().toLowerCase();
    }
```