# Make Filter works properly with Array Object property in Angular Material Data Table

Tags: arrays, angular, filter, angular-material

I have an Angular material data table which is implemented in the way that described in Angular Material documentation:

https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#filtering

My issue is with my data source, I have this data model:

```
export interface CustomerHistory {
  entity_id: number;
  email: string;
  name: string;
  lastname: string;
  cpfcnpj: string;
  cpfcnpj2: string;
  rg: string;
  phone1: string;
  phone2: string;
  country: string;
  state: string;
  city: string;
  address: string;
  FullAddress: string;
  cep: string;
  orders: CustomerOrders[];
}
```

The last Property is Order Array which is causing filter not working properly in the way that works with other fields

**This is my Filter Function:**

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
}
```

**My question is how can I search in Array Object property in my data source?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering specific column in Angular Material Table with filtering in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939979/filtering-specific-column-in-angular-material-table-with-filtering-in-angular)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when you drawTable make sure to create a loop like

```
    this.dataSource.data.orders.forEach(element => {
    element.toString();
//turn CustomerOrders[] to string
});
```

After that, applyFilter() should work

```
`applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
}`
```