# Filtering specific column in Angular Material table with more filter values (each column more than 1 selection)

Tags: angular, angular-material

If I have to select filter from `dropdownlist` with check boxes. So user can select more than 1 filter for each specific column. How could it.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getRemoteData();

    // Overrride default filter behaviour of Material Datatable
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.createFilter();
}
...

// Custom filter method fot Angular Material Datatable
createFilter() {
    let filterFunction = function (data: any, filter: string): boolean {
        let searchTerms = JSON.parse(filter);
        let isFilterSet = false;
        for (const col in searchTerms) {
            if (searchTerms[col].toString() !== '') {
                isFilterSet = true;
            } else {
                delete searchTerms[col];
            }
        }

        let nameSearch = () => {
            let found = false;
            if (isFilterSet) {
                for (const col in searchTerms) {
                    for (const element in col) {
                        searchTerms[col].[element ].trim().toLowerCase().split(' ').forEach(word => {
                            if (data[col].[element ].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) != -1 && isFilterSet) {
                                found = true
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return found
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return nameSearch()
    }
    return filterFunction
}
```

Comment: I think your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939979/filtering-specific-column-in-angular-material-table-with-filtering-in-angular

Comment: Thanks for responding. Actually this question is extension of code spy's reponse from the link you provided. So my question is  what changes have to be made so user can select multiple values for filtering from a specific column?