# Material table datasource filter with column value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

How can I filter the material data table with specific column ?

```
public dataSource;


this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.items);
        this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function customFilter(data , filter:string ): boolean {
            return (data.name.startsWith(filter));
        }

applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
}
```

---

The above code is not working,  when I type returns as no data is matched.

Comment: Did you apply the filter?

Comment: @David Ya I have applied the filter.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From [the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#filtering).

> For example, the data object {id: 123, name: 'Mr. Smith', favoriteColor: 'blue'} will be reduced to 123mr. smithblue. If your filter string was blue then it would be considered a match because it is contained in the reduced string, and the row would be displayed in the table.
>
> To override the default filtering behavior, a custom filterPredicate
> function can be set which takes a data object and filter string and
> returns true if the data object is considered a match.

If you want to use filter only specific columns you need to override `filterPredicate` and the answer already is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276404/filtering-specific-column-in-angular-material-table-in-angular-5).

This is the working example for filtering.

**table-filtering-example.html**

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <div class="example-header">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

**table-filtering-example.ts**

```
  import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
    
    /**
     * @title Table with filtering
     */
    @Component({
      selector: 'table-filtering-example',
      styleUrls: ['table-filtering-example.css'],
      templateUrl: 'table-filtering-example.html',
    })
    export class TableFilteringExample {
      displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
      dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
    
      applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
        filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
        filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
      }
    }
    
    export interface Element {
      name: string;
      position: number;
      weight: number;
      symbol: string;
    }
    
    const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
      {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
      {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
      {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
      {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
      {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
      {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
      {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
      {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
      {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
      {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
      {position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na'},
      {position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg'},
      {position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al'},
      {position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si'},
      {position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P'},
      {position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S'},
      {position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl'},
      {position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar'},
      {position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K'},
      {position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca'}, ];
```

---

you can use filterPredicate to filter specific column like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: Element, filter: string) => {
      return data.name == filter;
     };
   }
 applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    // filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    // filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
```

I have changed the `applyFilter()` and added `ngOnInit()`. Now it is working only **name** column and exactly same value `(==)`

Comment: I need to filter with specific column.

Comment: please check the answer. I have added the specific column filter answer and checked it is working. @bereketgebredingle

Comment: what if I want to export the filtered data in say excel workbook. So I am able to export the data to excel but I want to limit the data to the data which is filtered out by our custom predicate. Please help

Comment: Excellent solution!  filterPredicate is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You can get to filter by a dynamic column, as in **no hardcoded column name**, doing the following:

```js
// On input focus: setup filterPredicate to only filter by input column
setupFilter(column: string) {
  this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (d: TableDataSourceType, filter: string) => {
    const textToSearch = d[column] && d[column].toLowerCase() || '';
    return textToSearch.indexOf(filter) !== -1;
  };
}

applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
  this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

In the template you can have something like this:

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="item-filter">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    <input (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" (focus)="setupFilter('name')" />
  </th>
</ng-container>
```

Or a more complex example, dynamically create a header row with per-column filtering:

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let filterCol of ['names', 'age', 'address']">
     <ng-container matColumnDef="filterCol">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
         <input (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" (focus)="setupFilter(filterCol)"/>
       </th>
     </ng-container>
   </ng-container>

   <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['names', 'age', 'address']"></tr>
</table>
```

Be aware that you **cannot** have multiple header rows with the same keys, so this will not work:

```html
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['names', 'age', 'address']"></tr>
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['names', 'age', 'address']"></tr>
```

Comment: and how to apply multiple filters with this solution ?

Comment: Your solution it's just for one column. A real scenario it's with AND not with OR like it's yours...

Answer (score 8):

Create custom filter select box for the Material table using **filterPredicate** to override with **customFilter()** method

**Demo [Link](https://freakyjolly.com/demo/Angular/angular-material-table-custom-filters-for-multiple-specific-column/)**

**Source [Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-material-table-custom-filter-using-select-box/)**
[image]

```
        ...
        ngOnInit() {
            this.getRemoteData();

            // Overrride default filter behaviour of Material Datatable
            this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.createFilter();
        }
        ...

        // Custom filter method fot Angular Material Datatable
        createFilter() {
            let filterFunction = function (data: any, filter: string): boolean {
            let searchTerms = JSON.parse(filter);
            let isFilterSet = false;
            for (const col in searchTerms) {
                if (searchTerms[col].toString() !== '') {
                isFilterSet = true;
                } else {
                delete searchTerms[col];
                }
            }

            let nameSearch = () => {
                let found = false;
                if (isFilterSet) {
                for (const col in searchTerms) {
                    searchTerms[col].trim().toLowerCase().split(' ').forEach(word => {
                    if (data[col].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) != -1 && isFilterSet) {
                        found = true
                    }
                    });
                }
                return found
                } else {
                return true;
                }
            }
            return nameSearch()
            }
            return filterFunction
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

**app.compont.html**

```
 <mat-form-field floatPlaceholder="never">
            <input matInput placeholder="Filter name" (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)">
          </mat-form-field>
        <mat-table matSort  [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
           
            <!-- Position Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
          
            <!-- Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
          
            <!-- Weight Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Weight </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
          
            <!-- Symbol Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
          
            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
          </mat-table>
          <mat-paginator [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
  { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
  { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' },
  { position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C' },
  { position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N' },
  { position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O' },
  { position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F' },
  { position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne' },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mat-table',
  templateUrl: './mat-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mat-table.component.css'],
})
export class MatTableComponent {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    if (filterValue == '') {
        this.tablesource = this.filteresource;
    }
    else if (filterValue != '') {
        this.tablesource = this.filteresource.filter(e =>
            e.galleryDesc.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue.trim().toLowerCase()) ||
            e.galleryName.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue.trim().toLowerCase()) ||
            e.status.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filterValue.trim().toLowerCase()) ||
            e.createdDate.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue.trim().toLowerCase())
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: filtering betwen another field in typescript

Answer (score 0):

try this one- inline filter using mat-input, mat-icon and multi-header rows
https://angular-material-table-multiple-header-rows-hyfefz.stackblitz.io/

**[image: strong text]**

Answer (score 0):

FilterPredicate is just a function that filters the source data by catching a row, and if a row exists, it returns true. So I created a formGroup with exactly the same names as columns, and with that, I wrote the filterPreticate function to file the date.

```
 this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (
    data: { [name: string]: unknown },
    filter: { [name: string]: unknown }
  ): boolean => {
    for (const key in filter) {
      if (key in data) {
        if (
          data[key].toString().trim().toLowerCase() !==
          filter[key].toString().trim().toLowerCase()
        ) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  };
```

Also, I removed all undefined, null, or'' key values from formValue Obj before passing the value.

```
applyFilter() {
 const cleanObject: { [name: string]: unknown } = {};
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(
    this.filterForm.value as { [name: string]: unknown }
  )) {
    if (value !== undefined && value !== null && value !== '') {
      cleanObject[key] = value;
    }
  }
  this.dataSource.filter = cleanObject;
}
```

If you want your filter to filer columns with subsctring, you can use this code.

```
  this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (
    data: { [name: string]: unknown },
    filter: { [name: string]: unknown }
  ): boolean => {
    for (const key in filter) {
      if (key in data && typeof data[key] === 'string') {
        const dataValue = data[key].toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        const filterValue = filter[key].toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        if (!(dataValue.indexOf(filterValue) !== -1)) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  };
```