# How to filter a table using multiple set values

Tags: html, angular, typescript, material-design

I have an angular 7 Mat-Data-Table that I'm using to show data I'm getting from an API. 
I want to use 3 parameters that i get from the client and i save them into values using snapshot.
the problem I'm facing now is how do I make it so that the table will be filtered by the choices of the the client in `NgOninit`.

This is my Component :

```
export class ContainersPageComponent implements OnInit {

  tableColumn = ['AITOR','SOG_MCOLH','GOBH_MCOLH','AORKH_MCOLH','MCOLH_N7','MCOLH_AAAA', 'TAOR_QTSR_EBRI','QOD_MCHSN','STTOS_RASHI_4_1',
'LQOCH_SHM_MQOTSR_EBRI','LQOCH_SHM_LOEZI_QTSR','LQOCH_QOD_LQOCH'];

  p :number = 1;
  dataSource : any = new MatTableDataSource;
  public show:boolean = false;
  public tableHide:any = 'Show';
  searchText: string = "";
  autoFilter : any;
  clientType : string;
  storageType: any;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;


  filterCheckboxes: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

  constructor(private marinService:MarinServiceService,private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.marinService.getAllContainers().subscribe((result) => {
     //Data
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result);
      //Paginator
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      //AutoFilter Form 1st page
      this.clientType = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('clientType');
      this.storageType= this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('storageTypes');
      console.log('The Client name is : '+this.clientType+'  '+'The storage Facility is : '+this.storageType);
      //CheckBox Filter
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: Container, filter: any) => {
        return filter.split(',').every((item: any) => data.SOG_MCOLH.indexOf(item) !== -1);
      };
      this.filterCheckboxes.subscribe((newFilterValue: any[]) => {
        this.dataSource.filter = newFilterValue.join(',');
      });

    });
  }



  toggle(){
    this.show = !this.show;

    if(this.show) {
      this.tableHide = "Hide";
    } else {
      this.tableHide = "Show";
    }
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  public getRowsValue(flag) {
    if (flag === null) {
      return this.dataSource.length;
    } else {
      return this.dataSource.filter(i => (i.state == flag)).length;
    }
  }

  addFilter(change: MatCheckboxChange) {
    if (this.filterCheckboxes.value.some((a: any) => a === change.source.value)) {
      this.filterCheckboxes.next(this.filterCheckboxes.value.filter((a: any) => a !== change.source.value));
    } else {
      this.filterCheckboxes.next(this.filterCheckboxes.value.concat(change.source.value));
    }
  }
}
```

This is my HTML :

```
<div>
    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  [hidden]="!show" matSort >
      <!-- Location  -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="AITOR">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Location </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.AITOR}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
          <!-- Type  -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="SOG_MCOLH">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header > Container Type </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.SOG_MCOLH}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
              <!-- Height  -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="GOBH_MCOLH">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Container Height </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.GOBH_MCOLH}} </mat-cell>
              </ng-container>    
              <!-- Length  -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="AORKH_MCOLH">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Container Lenght </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.AORKH_MCOLH}} </mat-cell>
              </ng-container> 
               <!-- Number  -->
               <ng-container matColumnDef="MCOLH_N7">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Container Number </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.MCOLH_N7}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container> 
                    <!-- Name AAAA  -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="MCOLH_AAAA">
                      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Container Name </mat-header-cell>
                      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.MCOLH_AAAA}} </mat-cell>
                      </ng-container>  
                     <!-- QTSR Hebrow  -->
                     <ng-container matColumnDef="TAOR_QTSR_EBRI">
                     <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Storage Site </mat-header-cell>
                     <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.TAOR_QTSR_EBRI}} </mat-cell>
                     </ng-container>   
                                  <!-- Storage Code  -->
                                  <ng-container matColumnDef="QOD_MCHSN">
                                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Storage Code </mat-header-cell>
                                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.QOD_MCHSN}} </mat-cell>
                                    </ng-container>
                                 <!-- Status  -->
                                  <ng-container matColumnDef="STTOS_RASHI_4_1">
                                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </mat-header-cell>
                                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.STTOS_RASHI_4_1}} </mat-cell>
                                    </ng-container>      
                                  <!-- MQOTSR Hebrow  -->
                                  <ng-container matColumnDef="LQOCH_SHM_MQOTSR_EBRI">
                                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Customer MQOTSR </mat-header-cell>
                                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.LQOCH_SHM_MQOTSR_EBRI}} </mat-cell>
                                    </ng-container>
                                  <!-- MQOTSR Hebrow  -->
                                  <ng-container matColumnDef="LQOCH_SHM_LOEZI_QTSR">
                                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ESN </mat-header-cell>
                                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.LQOCH_SHM_LOEZI_QTSR}} </mat-cell>
                                    </ng-container>
                                  <!-- MQOTSR Hebrow  -->
                                  <ng-container matColumnDef="LQOCH_QOD_LQOCH">
                                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Code Customer </mat-header-cell>
                                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.LQOCH_QOD_LQOCH}} </mat-cell>
                                    </ng-container>            

    <!--Row Maker-->
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableColumn"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableColumn;" ></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
    </div>
```

I have tried using pipes but I don't really understand them.

Comment: Can't really help without a working stackblitz of the same

Comment: @NicholasK its a huge project i could have uploaded it directly to StackBlitz i would but as there is no way to upload it currently to Stackblitz directly i cant write it there too.

Comment: See [this simplified solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f3mmmp) on stackblitz - instead of reading the data from valueChange, read it from your snapshot. ([Original SO Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276404/filtering-specific-column-in-angular-material-table-in-angular-5))

Comment: @Yaelet thank you for the helping but this is not what I'm trying to do. i want to filter my table without the use of  user text input. the component saves the values from the URL params and uses the values stored from the snapshot. the only problem is how to use those values to filter the table without other inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to read three values from the `snapshot`, but your code sample shows two. It's also not clear how the data read from the `snapshot` relates to the filters.
I made an assumption that the two fields you stored are those to be filtered.

Essentially, you assign an initial value to the `dataSource.filter`, as the `BehaviourSubject` has nothing to emit.

```
...

 ngOnInit() {
    this.marinService.getAllContainers().subscribe((result) => {

      ...

      // get snapshot data
      this.clientType = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('clientType');
      this.storageType= this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('storageTypes');
      console.log('The Client name is : '+this.clientType+'  '+'The storage Facility is : '+this.storageType);

      ...

      this.filterCheckboxes.subscribe((newFilterValue: any[]) => {
        this.dataSource.filter = newFilterValue.join(',');
      });

      // set the filter to the dataSource
      this.dataSource.filter = ` ${this.clientType},${this.storageType}`;

      // Make changes to UI to reflect the filter
      // ....
    });
  }
```

You could, alternatively, call `next()` on the `BehaviourSubject` inside the `ngOnInit` to set the filter

```
...

 ngOnInit() {
    this.marinService.getAllContainers().subscribe((result) => {

      ...

      // get snapshot data
      this.clientType = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('clientType');
      this.storageType= this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('storageTypes');
      console.log('The Client name is : '+this.clientType+'  '+'The storage Facility is : '+this.storageType);

      ...

      this.filterCheckboxes.subscribe((newFilterValue: any[]) => {
        this.dataSource.filter = newFilterValue.join(',');
      });

      // set the filter via the filterCheckbox
      this.filterCheckboxes.next([this.clientType, this.storageType]);

      // Make changes to UI to reflect the filter
      // ....
    });
  }
```