# Is there any way to filter by each column of dynamic mat table? Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

So I need to have a filter for each column in angular material table but table headers are dynamic. I couldn't find soultion for dynamic headers, I only find out how to filter through static headers.

I want something like this but with dynamic headers:

[image]

Anyone have any solutions?

Comment: I resolved this. Found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276404/filtering-specific-column-in-angular-material-table-in-angular-5/54577092#54577092

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a form with column keys you want to filter
2. Subscribe form and create a predicate
3. On HTML side, based on column key (dynamic key) get form control

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arwyyd?file=src/app/app.component.html) example.

Comment: What if I don't know the columnDef before I fetch data from an API?